# システムへの戻り値

Tags: python

お世話になります。

他の言語から、pythonスクリプトを呼び出し、戻り値を返すことは可能でしょうか？

例えば、シェルスクリプトの中から、jholidya.pyを呼び出し、戻り値から条件分岐するなど

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sys.exit](http://docs.python.jp/2/library/sys.html)(ステータスコード(整数)）を使います。